# Preserve FlipView selected item on GoBack navigation?

Tags: windows-8

I have an app with two levels of a LayoutAware pages with FlipViews. 
GoBack is causing me headaches since it remembers my original navigation parameter instead of saving its last state when it was navigated away from.

Navigation flow:

1) MainPage:

Selecting an item navigates to the flip view page with the current item selected:
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemFlipViewPage), selectedItem1);

2) ItemFlipViewPage:
Set FlipView selected item based on LoadState navigation parameter (selectedItem1 in this example)

Change the FlipView's selected item (for example selectedItem3) and navigate to the GalleryFlipViewPage:

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GalleryFlipViewPage), selectedItem3_Image1);

3) GalleryFlipViewPage:

Clicking the GoBack button causes ItemFlpViewPage to be loaded with the original Navigation parameter of selectedItem1.

*What's the best way to preserve my selected item on GoBack?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Page.NavigationCacheMode="Required"`.

Comment: That solves the problem but introduces a new one. When I go back to the main page and then click on a new item, the previously cached page appears instead.

Comment: In that case it might actually be better to leave in its default `NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"` setting, but make sure you stored the properties you want restored keyed by the parameter you pass when you navigate to that page. Alternatively you could clear out the entered/cached values when you navigate forward to that page, but note that would also clear it out if you went back through the `Frame` back stack and get to the page that was already cleared by going forward to it elsewhere. It all depends on your navigation model.